# Evaluate $\int_{|z-1|=3} \frac{z-2}{z(z-1)(z+2)}dz$ using residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus

I need to evaluate $$\int_{|z-1|=3} \frac{z-2}{z(z-1)(z+2)}dz$$
So the integrand has 3 poles of order 1: $z=0$, $z=1$ and $z=-2$. But $z=-2$ lies on the contour itself. I found out that I need to calculate Cauchy Principal Value, but I can't understand how.

Comment: Hint: start with $$\frac{z-2}{z(z-1)(z+2)}=\frac{1}{z}-\frac{2}{3(z+2)}-\frac{1}{3(z-1)}$$

Comment: Make a cut around the singular point on the contour. Then let the diameter of the cut tend to zero.

Answer (score 1):

The principal value is normally assessed by cutting out a small portion, say length $2 \varepsilon$, symmetrically on either side of the singularity, evaluate the integral on the resulting contour and then allow $\varepsilon \to 0$.  If this has a limit then that is the principal value.

Applying it to your case, let $I$ be the integral taken round the circular contour but stopping at a distance of $\varepsilon$ each side of $z=-2$.  Then add each of two paths to $I$.  The first, $J_1$ joins the ends of $I$ in a nearly circular arc so that combined $I$ and $J_1$ enclose $z=-2$.  The second, $J_2$, also joins the ends of $I$ using a circular arc, but excluding $z=-2$.

If the residues at the poles are $r_1, r_2, r_3$, with that at $z=-2 = r_1$ then, irrespective of $\varepsilon$,
$$I+J_1 = 2\pi i (r_1+r_2+r_3), \quad I+J_2 = 2\pi i(r_2+r_3)$$
Now the "Indentation Lemma" states that if $f$ is holomorphic except at a *simple* pole at $z=a$ where it has residue $b$, taking a contour $\gamma=a + \varepsilon e^{i\theta}$ for $\theta_1 \leqslant \theta \leqslant \theta_2$, then as $\varepsilon \to 0$,
$$\int_{\gamma} f(z)dz \to ib(\theta_2-\theta_1).$$

Using it for $J_1$ and $J_2$, noting their respective orientations, as $\varepsilon \to 0$ both $J_1, J_2$ become semi-circular, and by this lemma, $J_1$ and $-J_2$ will have limit $\pi i r_1 $ and $J_1+J_2 \to 0$.  We now have,
$$2I = 2 \cdot 2\pi i (r_2+r_3) + 2\pi i r_1 - (J_1+J_2).$$
Let $\varepsilon \to 0$, to obtain,
$$I = 2\pi i \big(\tfrac{1}{2} r_1+r_2+r_3 \big)$$